# How to build code containing cuda function and c++ template function

Tags: c++, stl, cuda

The code is as follow:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T> void InsertValueNode(std::list<T> &ValueList,T NewValue)
{
    std::list<T>::iterator itCurVal = ValueList.begin();
    while(itCurVal != ValueList.end())
    {
        if(NewValue < (*itCurVal))
            break;
        itCurVal++;
    }
    std::insert_iterator< std::list<T> > itNewNode(ValueList, itCurVal);
    *itNewNode = NewValue;
}

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

//to simplify the problem, just imply an empty main function
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The aboving code is in a .cu file in a visual studio 2010 project. The problem is compiler can not recognize STL iterator definition when compiling:

```
error : identifier "itNumerical" is undefined
error : identifier "itCurVal" is undefined
error : expected a ";"
```

If I rename the file as .cpp and rebuild, the code can be compiled, but a link error that "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx" occurs. 
So how to build the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* be a limitation of the CUDA C++ front-end/parser breaking on the standard library templates. I can reproduce it with CUDA 8 and gcc 4.8.5.

As a workaround, this appears to work:

```
template<class T> void InsertValueNode(std::list<T> &ValueList,T NewValue)
{
    auto itCurVal = ValueList.begin();
    while(itCurVal != ValueList.end())
    {
        if(NewValue < (*itCurVal))
            break;
        itCurVal++;
    }
    std::insert_iterator< std::list<T> > itNewNode(ValueList, itCurVal);
    *itNewNode = NewValue;
}
```

when using nvcc to steer the compilation as long as the `-std=c++11` option is used. You might want to contemplate filing a bug report with NVIDIA